# Ip connectivity with two interfcaes

Tags: linux, ip, routing

I have two network interfaces in Linux machine , eth0 and eth1. IP is assigned to both interface from two different VLANs and default gateway to eth0. Now if interface eth0 is down I am unable to route traffic outside as default gateway is also unavailable.

Is there is any way to address this scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear from your description, are both interfaces connected to the same network.
Anyway,:
let's assume
you have
eth0 - 192.168.10.10/24, gw 192.168.10.1
eth0 - 170.10.0.10/24,   gw 170.10.0.1

1. create new rule
   `#ip ru add table 5 prio 20000 from 170.10.0.10`
2. create new default rule
   `#ip ro add table 5 default via 170.10.0.1'

so, you can check the settings by:
`#ip ru sh` - see rules

`0:  from all lookup local

20000:  from 170.10.0.10 lookup 5`

`#ip ro sh ta 5` - see routing for you table

`default via 170.10.0.1 dev eth1`

BTW, there is a good reading concerning linux routing [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://lartc.org)

Comment: hi,
It is connected to same network but different VLAN. From above solution if eth0 is goes down , then eth1 default gw will work?

Comment: this solution will work independently to VLANs, but it has some obvious limitation - if you receive IPs via DHCP/SLAAC - it will be difficult to add such rule/route